# How do I configure Jest to work with the MSSQL NodeJS package?

Tags: sql-server, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to test a NextJS app that uses a Microsoft SQL Server backend. I have a test set up like so:

```
import { executeQuery } from "@/app/api/databaseStuff/database";

it("returns 401 if user has no valid subscription",async ()=>{
    global.fetch = jest.fn((input:URL | RequestInfo,init: RequestInit | undefined) => Promise.resolve(({ok:true,json: async ()=>({url:"https://www.website.com/placeholder.png",revised_prompt:"test"})}) as Response));
    // create fake subscription
    const fakeFbId = "fb_1234567890";
    const fakeFbUserAuth: FacebookUserAuth = {userID: fakeFbId,accessToken: "01510414124141"};
    const fakeToken = jwt.sign(fakeFbUserAuth,jwtKey);
    const mockRequest = {
        cookies: {get: (key:string)=>(key === "jsonWebToken" ? {value: fakeToken} : null)},
        nextUrl:new URL("https://website.app/api/customer/openai/generateCaption")};
    mockRequest.nextUrl.searchParams.set("caption","test2");
    const fakeStripeId = "cus_1234567890";
    const fakeSubscriptionID = "sub_0123456789";
    const fakePlanId = "prod_S3R24SZLXMPOT1";
    await executeQuery("INSERT INTO [user] (fb_id,stripe_id) VALUES (@fbIdParam,@stripeIdParam)",[{name: "fbIdParam",value:fakeFbId},{name:"stripeIdParam",value:fakeStripeId}]);
    const response = await GET(mockRequest as NextRequest);
    expect(response?.status).toBe(402);
});
```

Here's the imported file:

```
import sql from 'mssql';

const dbConfig = {
  user: process.env.DB_USER!,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD!,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME!,
  server: process.env.DB_HOST!,
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: true, // for Azure SQL DB
    trustServerCertificate: process.env.DB_TRUST_CERT?.toLowerCase() === "true" // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
  }
};
/**
 * 
 * @returns If successful, a MSSQL connection pool. Else, NULL.
 */

export async function getConnectionPool() {
  try {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
    const connection = await pool.connect();
    return connection;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`Database connection failed: ${err}`)
  }
}

type SqlParam = {name: string, value:string | number}
export async function executeQuery(query:string,params:SqlParam[]) {
    const pool = await getConnectionPool();
    // Create a request from the pool
    const request = pool.request();
    for (const parameter of params)
    {
        request.input(parameter.name,parameter.value);
    }
    // Execute the query
    try
    {
      const result = await request.query(query);
      return result;
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      throw `could not execute query "${query} with params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}: ${e}`;
    }
    
};
```

When I run my test, Jest complains:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      17 | };
      18 | /**
    > 19 |  *
         |              ^
      20 |  * @returns If successful, a MSSQL connection pool. Else, NULL.
      21 |  */
      22 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@azure/msal-node/dist/crypto/GuidGenerator.cjs:5:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@azure/msal-node/dist/crypto/CryptoProvider.cjs:5:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@azure/msal-node/dist/client/ClientApplication.cjs:7:22)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@azure/msal-node/dist/client/PublicClientApplication.cjs:7:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@azure/msal-node/dist/index.cjs:6:31)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:5:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/tedious/src/connection.ts:12:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/tedious/src/tedious.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:3:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/index.js:4:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mssql/index.js:1:182)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/api/databaseStuff/database.ts:19:55)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/subscriptionTable.ts:13:19)
```

I seem to have explicitly told Jest to transform the module causing the error, though the error still occurs. My `jest.config.ts` file looks like this:

```
import type { Config } from 'jest'
import nextJest from 'next/jest.js'
import * as jest from "jest";
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})
 
// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const config: Config = {
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!@azure/msal-node).+\\.js$"
  ],
  setupFiles: ['./dotenv.config.ts'],
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/*.test.ts','**/__tests__/**/*.ts'],
  reporters: [["jest-summarizing-reporter",{"diffs":true}]],
}
 
// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
export default createJestConfig(config)
```

- Node version: 20.11.0
- Jest version: 29.7.0
- `MSSQL` library version: 10.0.1
- Next version: 13.5.5

Comment: To whomever edited my question yesterday - thanks for helping clean up the question.

However, my question does not involve T-SQL. I'm trying to invoke the "mssql" NPM package in a Jest test and Jest isn't happy about it.